# Disabling a button in javaFX and enable it again

Tags: java

Hi guy I just started learn some JavaFX and I made a simple product TableView program which you can add and delete items. the items include name price and quantity.
I tried to prevent a bug so I did everytime the name\price\quantity fields are empty the add button will be disabled.

```
     addButton = new Button("Add");
    if(name.getText().isEmpty()&& price.getText().isEmpty() && quantity.getText().isEmpty()) {
        addButton.setDisable(true);
    } else {
        addButton.setDisable(false);
        addButton.setOnAction(e-> addButtonClicked());
    }
```

The button is indeed disable but when I input some data to the field it remain disable.

[image]

I would like if someone can help me figure it out.
srry for the broken english ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed this, if someone got the same issue this is the solution :

```
  addButton = new Button("Add");
    addButton.disableProperty().bind(
            name.textProperty().isEmpty()
                    .or(price.textProperty().isEmpty())
                    .or(quantity.textProperty().isEmpty())
    );
```